# Install PgAgent 4.0 on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, pgadmin-4, pgagent

I have Postgresql server 12.1 running at Debian 9.11 & I managed the databases with pgadmin 4.18 at the windows client.

Later at the server I installed pgagent:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgagent
```

I found that pgagent.sql is created in /usr/share/pgadmin3 & it is version 3.4. When I opened pgadmin, pgagent is not appear under Extension. I tried CREATE EXTENSION pgagent but error shown as below:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

Obviously the version of pgagent is too old for postgresql 12.
How to install pgagent 4 on debian so that I can configure it using my Pgadmin 4.18?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I downloaded the deb from https://debian.pkgs.org/9/postgresql-amd64/pgagent_4.0.0-6.pgdg90+1_amd64.deb.html & installed it using dpkg.